# What is our stance on questions on Electronic Medical Record (EMR) systems?

Tags: discussion, scope

What is our stance on questions on Electronic Medical Record (EMR) systems? Are they on-topic or off-topic?

Example:

> Subject: Is there a list of Electronic Medical Record (EMR) systems
>   that Dragon Professional Individual intentionally do not support?
>
> Body: http://shop.nuance.com/store/nuanceus/Custom/pbpage.dragonProINDV/ 
>   ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170327151654/http://shop.nuance.com/store/nuanceus/Custom/pbpage.dragonProINDV))
>   says:
>
> > Note: Does not support dictation into Electronic Medical Record (EMR) systems. For EMR support, please use Dragon Medical Practice Edition
>
> Is there a list of Electronic Medical Record (EMR) systems that Dragon
>   intentionally do not support?

Comment: Maybe this might help to assuage the curiosity which prompted you to ask your question: http://www.speakeasysolutions.com/blog/2012/01/24/dragon-medical-vs-non-medical-dragon-naturallyspeaking-premium/

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the thrust of the question. Does it affect the health of a cohort? Not really, so I would not really deem this question to be on topic. EHR questions *can* be on topic depending on the subject, but this is not really one of them.

I have seen this exact question closed on other sites, but I think the answer is implicit in the question.

> Note: Does not support dictation into Electronic Medical Record (EMR)
>   systems. For EMR support, please use Dragon Medical Practice Edition

I would say that intentionally they don't support it so that you have to buy a different edition, but the only answer would be to talk to Dragon.